# Passing a variable using an onclick event to a function for a dynamically created button

Tags: jquery

Please find the code below. When I'm trying to pass the variable tmp_lnk from the onclick event to the function it throws up an error that tmp_lnk is not defined. How do I pass the variable to the function?

```
if(fig_name[1]==img_name)
{
var tmp_lnk = "Supplementary Notes for Images/"+"6H-"+img_name/img_name+".pdf"
$("#notes1").append('<div><a onclick="On_Click(tmp_lnk)" id="closebutton">NOTES</a></div>')
break;
}}

function On_Click(tmp_link)
{
    window.open("tmp_lnk");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#notes1").append('<div><a onclick="On_Click(' + tmp_lnk+ ')" id="closebutton">NOTES</a></div>')
```

And

```
function On_Click(tmp_lnk)
{
    window.open(tmp_lnk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, how about this:

```
$("#notes1").append('<div><a onclick="On_Click('+tmp_lnk+')" id="closebutton">NOTES</a></div>')
```

That would make the variable content written on the method call, solving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

because you declare the tmp_lnk in if make it global or declare out side of the if

```
var tmp_lnk
if(fig_name[1]==img_name)
{
tmp_lnk = "Supplementary Notes for Images/"+"6H-"+img_name/img_name+".pdf"
$("#notes1").append('<div><a onclick="On_Click(tmp_lnk)" id="closebutton">NOTES</a></div>')
break;
}}

function On_Click(tmp_link)
{
    window.open("tmp_lnk");
}
}
```

**Good Read**

## [JavaScript Variable Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)